# Where do files ending with a ~ come from?

Tags: backup, files, filename

Sometimes duplicate filenames occur while working on Ubuntu which differ only by a `~` from the original filenames.

I know kate generates backup files and calls them `your_file.py.swp`. Is this something similar? If yes which program generates them? And why don't they disappear?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using gedit to edit existing files, the default preference is to "Create a backup of files before saving". If you would like to change this default behavior, open gedit, then go up to the Menu bar and select Edit --> Preferences. Click on the Editor Tab, and Uncheck the box under **File Saving** in order to turn it off.

[image]

Another common `~` file creator is `emacs` - some would argue it's even more popular/common than gedit.

Comment: wow. i always wondered about that. just turned gedit off because it was causing confusion when using git

Answer (score 8):

They are back up files , automatically generated as you say. Several applications use this format. Usually .swp files are made when the file is actually open for editing, and any automatic backup saved to file~

```
touch file

ls | grep file
file

nano -B file 
# make a change to file, save changes

ls | grep file
file
file~
```

I am not sure about kate, but unless you are using another editor, I presume it is automatic backups (every 10 minutes ? ) from kate.

Answer (score 5):

Kate generates them too.  You can turn them off or configure them differently in Settings > Configure Kate > Editor Component > Open/Save > Advanced.

[image: kate backup file config]